# Excel automated report sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpexcel, excel-2016

I have a data base of over 16k columns.
Each column is identified by an ID.
I am trying to make an automated daily report.
The data is updated every day.
I have 1 sheet which is (data) sheet.
I am planning on making a (report) sheet.
The rows in each column is like :

ID | Name | country | Position

I am planning on making different reports,
but for this example it's a report for whoever is from America
and is in a Manager Position as shown here:

| Id | Name | Country | Position |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 131 | Jhon | America | Manager |  |
| 918 | Smitg | Britain | Sampler |  |
| 519 | Nnasa | America | Manager |  |

The report should be like

| Id | Name | Country | Position |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 131 | Jhon | America | Manager |  |
| 519 | Nnasa | America | Manager |  |

New columns are added or deleted from time to time and are updated daily.

I appreciate the help

I have excel 2016

Comment: You tag Excel 2010 & 2007 which are you using? In your post you mention 2016, then why tag all except 2016?

Comment: Ah sorry for that I just dumbed whatever excel tag there is

Comment: So post some sample data (https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and expected output. Your current try and what you expect it to output versus what it currently outputs.

Comment: There's no real expected output it's kinda simple I have a huge data base but every day I have to filter whoever is American and in manager Postion and make a report out of them I just wanted to make it automatic it's just a filter thing

Comment: Without data it's not simple. Have you looked into using power query?

Comment: I added a sample and I have never heard of power query

Comment: You mean 16,000 rows by 5 columns?  I'd go with [Power Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/09/10/integrating-power-query-technology-in-excel-2016/) as @P.b suggested.

Comment: While vb could be effective for automation, taken handling a large dataset with 16k rows (growing presumably, without seeing actual data structures which sometimes can be complicated than expected) may become resource intensive anyway. Like other suggested for alternative approach, consider like power query, or Access could offer efficient solutions for handling large datasets.

Comment: Not 16k rows they are 16k columns with 120 rows

Comment: I wish I could post a photo